# PHP: Paginating over array creates unwanted additional value

Tags: php, arrays, pagination

I have an array of values that I am paginating over with a simple function. Everything is working fine except for one small bug which I can't seem to solve.

If you run the code below, you will get an array from 1 to 18 printed out over 4 pages. The `$per_page` variable dictates how many values are shown per page. In our case, we *should* have 4 pages (18 / 5 = 3.6, so the first three pages have 5 values each and the final fourth page has the remaining 3 -- or '0.6' -- values).

The bug is that page one has values 1 to 5, page two has values 5 to 9, page three has values 10 to 14, and page four has values 15 to 18. So for some reason **both pages one and two** are getting value 5, which is creating one extra value to be paginated. Further perplexing is why this is only happening with the final value on page one, but not on the proceeding pages.

Can you see how exactly I'm creating an additional value 5 to be paginated over, and how I can remove it?

```
<?php
$array = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18);

// PAGINATION FUNCTION
function paginateArray($array, $from, $per_page) {
    $i = 0; $page = 0;
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $page++; if ($from <= $page && $i < $per_page) { $i++; yield $key => $value; }
    }
}
$per_page = 5; // HOW MANY VALUES TO SHOW PER PAGE
$num_of_pages = count($array) / $per_page; // TOTAL NUMBER OF PAGES
$from = (int)(isset($_GET['from']) ? $_GET['from'] : 0); // GET USER NAVIGATION INPUT
unset($_GET['from']);

$content = ""; // DEFINE PAGE CONTENT
// APPEND PAGINATED ARRAY TO CONTENT
foreach (paginateArray($array, $from * $per_page, $per_page) as $array_item) {
    $content .= "$array_item<br>";
}

// PAGINATION NAVIGATION NUMBERS AND ARROWS
if ($from >= 1) { $content .= "<a href=?from=".($from - 1)."> < </a>  |  "; } else { $content .= "< | "; }
for ($i = 0; $i <= floor(($num_of_pages)); $i++) { if ($from !== $i) { $content .= "<a href=?from=$i>".($i + 1)."</a>  |  "; } else { $content .= "".($i +1)."  |  "; } }
if ($from <= ($num_of_pages - 1)) { $content .= "<a href=?from=".($from + 1)."> > </a>"; }  else { $content .= ">"; }

print $content; // PRINT CONTENT
?>
```

Comment: `$from <= $page` should be `$from < $page`

Comment: @Nick Thanks Nick...  That was it! How do I give you credit for answering the question if you've just commented? I'll post my final code in case anybody is interested in my pagination method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that when you are outputting subsequent pages, you are starting the output too early because you are comparing `$from` effectively with the *next* array index (since you increment `$page` before the comparison) and so you should use

```
$from < $page
```

rather than

```
$from <= $page
```

Note that you don't really need the `$page` variable in that code, you can just use the array key (`$key` in your code). For example:

```
function paginateArray($array, $from, $per_page) {
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if ($from <= $key && $i < $per_page) {
            $i++;
            yield $key => $value;
        }
    }
}
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/u9sGg)